# MDX Cumulative Values over non hierarchy attribute

Tags: mdx

I've been struggling for 3 days on this problem.

I will use AdventureWorks dimensions as an example (my cube has the same kind of setup).
I don't use the [Calendar] hierarchy here, because I want to show only Year / Month so I use [Calendar Year] and [Month of Year]

I want to show cumulative values for calendar months but since beginning of time, not current year.
The code behind is showing cumulative per month, but it resets every year.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CUM. MONTH]
 AS 
AGGREGATE(    
        {null:[Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember}
        * {null:[Date].[Month of Year].CurrentMember}
    , [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity])


 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity], [Measures].[CUM. MONTH] } ON COLUMNS
 , NON EMPTY { ([Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS
 * [Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year].ALLMEMBERS
 ) }
 
 
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
 FROM [Adventure Works]
 CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Results:

```
                          Qty      CUM. MONTH    WHAT I WANT
CY 2010  December          14         14             14
CY 2011  January          144        144            158
         February         144        288            302
         ...
         December         222      2,230          2,230
CY 2012  January          252        396          2,482
         February         260        800          2,734
```

As you can see, the CUM. MONTH is not only resetting every year, but it also adds same month from previous year:  2012 =  Jan 2012 + Feb 2012 + Feb 2011 = 396 + 260 + 144

Cumulative is working fine if I use the Calendar hierarchy, but I don't want to since users in Excel are putting Year / Month, they don't want to use the whole calendar hierarchy.